# Cant capture eventListener JS on Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, web

I cant get eventListener from a jsp page, i need a simple alert when click a button.

jsp code - this only draw a simple 3 buttons:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Click!</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="text-center p-5">
        <button class="btn btn-primary m-3" id="myBtn1">BTN1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary m-3" id="myBtn2">BTN2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary m-3" id="myBtn3">BTN3</button>
    </div>


<!-- JS -->
<script src="assets/js/sc.js"></script>
<!-- JS Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In js code put:

```
let id1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
id1.addEventListener("click", window.alert('BTN1'));
```

when open the navigator:

[image]

**Show the alert - but i dont push the button !**

When page is load show the buttons:

[image]

**when press BTN1 dont show alert.**

My folder extructure :

[image: Directory extructure]

The project is very simple i need to use correctly JavaScript on Spring Boot project.

Thanks for you helping !

Answer (score 1):

When you use the code `id1.addEventListener("click", window.alert('BTN1'));` you are using the `()` for the function which results in the calling of the function when the event listener is added.
To Prevent It, modify your js script as follows:

```
function idlistn(){window.alert('BTN1')}

let id1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
id1.addEventListener("click", idlistn);
```